# How to store the colors of SpatialPolygons in R

Tags: r, colors, shapefile, polygons

The code below is part of a small routine to store the LEGEND of colors used on a map.

The main function is to not use the PLOT function or the LEGEND function, but generate the polygons that form the LEGENDs and save them a shapefile.

```
contour <- bbox(mapa)
polBorder <- polygonBox(contour, scale=0.0002)
boxBorder <- bbox(polBorder)

polLeg <- list()

xmin <- boxBorder["x", "min"] + 0.0005
ymin <- boxBorder["y", "min"] + 0.0005
sizex = abs(boxBorder["x", "max"]-boxBorder["x", "min"])/20
sizey = abs(boxBorder["y", "max"]-boxBorder["y", "min"])/20

for (i in 1:7)
{
  polygon <- polygonBoxPos2(xmin, ymin, +sizex, +sizey, paste0("p",i))

  polLeg <- append(polygon, polLeg)

  ymin <- ymin + sizey

}

SdP = SpatialPolygons(polLeg)

plot(polBorder, border="black" )
plot(SdP, add=TRUE )
plot(mapa, col=colPalette,  add=TRUE)

polygonBox <- function (bbox, scale=0.0)
{

  bbox["x", "min"] <- bbox["x", "min"] + scale*bbox["x","min"]
  bbox["x", "max"] <- bbox["x", "max"] - scale*bbox["x","max"]

  bbox["y", "min"] <- bbox["y", "min"] + scale*bbox["y","min"]
  bbox["y", "max"] <- bbox["y", "max"] - scale*bbox["y","max"]

  Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(bbox["x","min"],bbox["x","max"],bbox["x","max"],bbox["x","min"],bbox["x","min"]),
                      c(bbox["y","min"],bbox["y","min"],bbox["y","max"],bbox["y","max"],bbox["y","min"]))
                , hole=TRUE)
  Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
  SdP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1))
  return(SdP)
}

polygonBoxPos2 <- function (xmin, ymin, sizex, sizey,id)
{

  xmax <- xmin + sizex
  ymax <- ymin + sizey

  Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(xmin , xmax , xmax , xmin, xmin ),c(ymin, ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin)), hole=TRUE)
  Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), id)

  return(Srs1)
}
```

You can see them at the bottom left.

All the examples I´ve searching set the polygons colors during the PLOT operation, but I want to store the color with the Polygon, how to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: This isn't clear or reproducible. Some of your functions aren't defined, and aren't in the obvious places (maptools and sp). Maybe you just need to create a list object with polygons and stored colours. Where are you getting the colours from anyway?

Comment: Sorry, I added the 2 functions I forgot. @Spacedman

Comment: The colors come from the palette I use to plot the map, in this example I was using brewer.pal(7,"Reds") from RColorBrewer

Comment: Righto - I think you want to create a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` with the required colour as one of the columns of the data frame. But if all you are trying to do is create coloured rectangles, the spatial stuff is probably overkill and you can draw them with R's rect function.

Comment: @Spacedman thanks, maybe I getting shapefiles wrong, do they have some way to represent colored filled polygons? If not maybe one solution could be to have the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with the color info and merge into .dbf polygon data. I thought I could save the shapefiles "colored" :)

Comment: Hmm saving the legend as a shapefile is kinda weird but I guess you think this is the way to import it into another package... You can't create a 'coloured' shapefile, you have to store the colour as an attribute, which gets stored in the .dbf, which you can create from a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` from your spatial polygons and a data frame constructed from your colours:

```
spdf = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Sr=SdP,
                                data=data.frame(
                                  id=1:length(colPalette),
                                  colour=colPalette,
                                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
                                match.ID=FALSE)
```

then you can plot this into your map by doing:

```
plot(spdf,col=spdf$colour, add=TRUE)
```

and then if you save it sing `writeOGR` to a Shapefile you might be able to use the `colour` attribute to shade it in whatever package you are loading these things into. I say "might" because its possible your GIS doesn't allow direct specification of colours from attributes, in which case you probably have to build a palette in your GIS, which is why I've also put an `id` attribute in there too.  But anyway, that's beyond the scope of your question now.